# UFW Active but Not Enabled After System Reboot in AlmaLinux 8.8 (Sapphire Caracal)

Tags: ufw, alma-linux

I'm encountering an issue with UFW (Uncomplicated Firewall) on my Linux system. After a system reboot, when I check the status of UFW using the `ufw status` command, it returns that the firewall is active. However, I've noticed that the firewall rules are not enabled until I manually execute `ufw reload`.

I expect that UFW should be enabled automatically at system startup, and I'd like to understand why this is happening and how to ensure that UFW is enabled without the need for manual intervention after each reboot.

Here are some additional details about my system configuration:

```
os version: AlmaLinux 8.8 (Sapphire Caracal) 
UFW version: 0.35
```

I enabled ufw at systemctl

Comment: what's the output of `sudo systemctl status ufw`